What are the Upalingams of lord Siva?
We all know that there are 12 jyotirlingas. However, I heard there are Upalingams as well. What are the Upalingams? Can anybody list them with references?

The upalingas are recorded in the Shiva Purana.

The Upalingas are mentioned in the Shiva Purana Koṭirudra-Saṃhitā Chapter 1 - The greatness of Jyotirlingas and their Upalingas.
ज्योतिषां चोपलिंगानि श्रूयन्तामृषिसत्तमाः ॥ ३४ ॥

O excellent sages, a few of the fruits of the Jyotirlingas have been
narrated by me. Let the Upalingas (ancillary phallic forms) of these
Jyotirlingas be listened to.

सोमेश्वरस्य यल्लिंगमन्तकेशमुदाहृतम् ।
मह्यास्सागरसंयोगे तल्लिंगमुपलिङ्गकम् ॥ ३५ ॥

The Upalinga of Someśvara is called Antakeśa and it is installed at
the confluence of the river Mahī and the ocean.

मल्लिकार्जुनसंभूतमुपलिंगमुदाहृतम् ।
रुद्रेश्वरमिति ख्यातं भृगुकक्षे सुखावहम् ॥ ३६ ॥

The Upalinga of Mallikārjuna is glorified as Rudreśvara. It is
pleasing and is stationed in Bhṛgukakṣa.

महाकालभवं लिंगं दुग्धेशमिति विश्रुतम् ।
नर्मदायां प्रसिद्धं तत्सर्वपापहरं स्मृतम् ॥ ३७ ॥

The Upalinga of Mahākāla is well known as Dugdheśa. It is famous in
the region of Narmadā and is remembered as destructive of all sins.

ॐकारजं च यल्लिंगं कर्दमेशमिति श्रुतम् ।
प्रसिद्धं बिन्दुसरसि सर्वकामफलप्रदम् ॥ ३८ ॥

The Upalinga of Oṃkāra is famous as Kardameśa in the Bindu lake and
yields the fruits of all desires.

केदारेश्वरसंजातं भूतेशं यमुना तटे ।
महापापहरं प्रोक्तं पश्यतामर्चतान्तथा ॥ ३९ ॥

The Upalinga of Kedāreśvara is Bhūteśa on the banks of the Yamunā. It
is destructive of sins of the visiting devotees.

भीमशंकरसंभूतं भीमेश्वरमिति स्मृतम् ।
सह्याचले प्रसिद्धं तन्महाबलविवर्द्धनम् ॥ ४० ॥

The Upalinga of Bhīmaśankara is Bhīmeśvara. It is famous in the Sahya
mountain and it causes the increase of great strength.

नागेश्वरसमुद्भूतं भूतेश्वरमुदाहृतम् ।
मल्लिकासरस्वतीतीरे दर्शनात्पापहारकम् ॥ ४१ ॥

The Upalinga of Nāgeśvara is Bhūteśvara. Installed on the banks of
Mallikāsarasvatī, it quells sins by the very sight.

रामेश्वराच्च यज्जातं गुप्तेश्वरमिति स्मृतम् ।
घुश्मेशाच्चैव यज्जातं व्याघ्रेश्वरमिति स्मृतम् ॥ ४२ ॥

The Upalinga attached to Rāmeśvara is Gupteśvara. The Upalinga
attached to Ghuśmeśa is Vyāghreśvara

ज्योतिर्लिंगोपलिंगानि प्रोक्तानीह मया द्विजाः ।
दर्शनात्पापहारीणि सर्वकामप्रदानि च ॥ ४३ ॥

O brahmins, thus I have mentioned the Upalingas and the Jyotirlingas.
They dispel sins by their sight and yield the fruit of all desires.

